# Should I use window.location.replace('/') or window.location.href=window.location.origin in the process of logging out?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In a logout button, should I be using `window.location.replace('/')` or `window.location.href=window.location.origin`. What is the difference between these two methods? I know that both of them clear the current href from the history, so the url won't be accessible to the user after logging out using either of them.

Comment: MDN: [window.location.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) & [window.location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href).
The difference from setting the href property value is that when using the location.replace() method, after navigating to the given URL, the current page will not be saved in session history — meaning the user won't be able to use the back button to navigate to it.

Comment: How is the [tag:next.js] tag relevant to this question? Because if you're asking which should you use in the context of a Next.js app, then the answer is neither. You should use the built-in [`next/router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router) instead. If you're simply asking about the differences between the two methods, then Next.js isn't relevant.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using next.js you can use next/router which is a better approach to it.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
const router = useRouter()
//and then you can do it like this 
router.replace('/')
//or
router.push('/')
```

Comment: I don't think this is answering OP question about the diff between the 2 methods.

Comment: He's asking about what should he use. I just gave him an alternative option.

Comment: @JoaquínVarela yes of course, thank you. Though beware that you can only call the useRouter hook inside a hook or a function component and not a regular javascript function, so it's limited if that is your use case.